How to move Thunderbird message preview to the bottom of the screen
I have just installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04, which comes with Thunderbird 115.10.1. When I click on messages, they appear on the right side of the screen. I would prefer for the messages to appear on the bottom of the screen. I would have expected to find these settings in Settings -> Layout, but they are not there. Could somebody please suggest where can these settings be found?

I was looking for the same. It is not intuitive if you are not by chance with some specific combination of settings . . .
Firstly - just confirm that you can toggle the reading pane by F8 key.
Then you need to see the Menu Bar, with the "View" menu available. If you don't - click on "three lines "in the top right corner, select "View" there, "Toolbars", tick "Menu Bar"
Then in the Inbox view, select "View" menu - Layout - Classic View or Wide View - as you prefer.
After these manipulations the reading pane might become empty.  Appear, but empty. Relaunch Thunderbird - it works after that!
To mention - Thunderbird, in my view, is the best mail client in how it maintains Local Folders !!! Clear location, unambiguous naming, possibility to copy between computers or archive as files without re-processing. It cannot be better!
Superb for keeping in local folders large mail archives with attachments etc. from your many previous email accounts.
Sergei

It’s a very long-winded way of saying: menu - view - layout; choose ‘classic view’ and that should give you the reading page at the bottom.
